# How to find angle of touch relative to some object?

Tags: ios, math, uigesturerecognizer, trigonometry, angle

I have some problems with angles and I hope you will help me :)

So, I need to find angle of the touch relative to the object (ball). I want to find the angle and set it to the ball. The problem I don't know how to find that angle. Now i'm using this code:

```
extension CGPoint {
var angle: CGFloat {
    get { return CGFloat(atan2(self.x, self.y)) }
}
```

But i have not correct angles with that code. Is there some easy way to get that angle?

Thank you for help!

[image: Picture here.]

Comment: what you're working out here is the angle from the origin to your touch point.  You need to use the difference between the touch point and the ball, (Xball - Xtouch) and (YBall - Ytouch)

Comment: Do you mean to use atan2(xBall - xTouch, yBall - yTouch)? Thank's for fast answer!

Comment: Should that or (touch - ball)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working this way too

Comment: Finally it work's good. So anybody who have such problem - do like this: atan2(Yobject - Ytouch, Xobject - Xtouch). Just change X and Y! Thanks's Russell :)